# Firefox not passing values from an input created by javascript function; IE works

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, dom, input

php code,
this is a small function to use javascript to create an input, then post those uploaded files to the next page.
it works well on IE, BUT Failed on FF. It will just pass the first and only file which not created by the js addMore().
IE:
Array([name] => Array([0] => j1.jpg) )

FIREFOX
Array([name] => Array([0] => j1.jpg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J85rd.jpg) => j2.jpg [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tivji.jpg) => j3.jpg)

a friend told me that the new node created by js DOM will not fit the old post...the DOM protocol... so the FF can't recognize it... is that right? how to correct that, thanks

```
//   html content


<td id="div1">
<input name="upload[]" id="upload" type="file" style="width:250px;" />                  
<input name="button" type="button" onClick="addMore()" value="+">
<br /> to add more files, please click the "+" button
</td>


//   js content
<script language="javascript">
    var addMore = function()  
 {  

     var div = document.getElementById("div1");  
     var br = document.createElement("br");  
     //var input = document.createElement("input");
     var input = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>0 ? document.createElement("<input name=\"upload[]\">") : document.createElement("input");
     var button = document.createElement("input");  

     input.setAttribute("type", "file");  
     input.setAttribute("name", "upload[]");
     input.setAttribute("id", "upload");
     button.setAttribute("type", "button");  
     button.setAttribute("value", "-");  
     button.onclick = function()  
     {  
         div.removeChild(br);  
         div.removeChild(input);  
         div.removeChild(button);  
     }  
     div.appendChild(br);  
     div.appendChild(input);  
     div.appendChild(button);  

}  
</script>
```

Comment: What HTML/Error produced in non-IE browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery to do this. you don't need to write all this code. jQuery.clone() would do the work. If you need something more fancy then you can use [this plugin](http://tristandenyer.com/using-jquery-to-duplicate-a-section-of-a-form-maintaining-accessibility/) to simply to achieve desired result with cross browser support. Here is a [demo of the plugin](http://tristandenyer.com/demos/dynamic-form.html).

Comment: thanks, it is helpful of your demo. but jQuery.clone() can copy one more input, but the value still not passing to the next page...the result is still the same as my old code...firefox...

Comment: thanks again...after my second check, it is right about my friends' advise, the so called DOM specification protocol... since my html structure is based on table, then the form tag must be contain the whole one...